# Clean Django form fields with same name

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I have a django template in which I'm dynamically rendering multiple fields (using ajax)
Below is a Django form (which has been rendered in a template) whose fields have same names. I want to use the `cleaned_data` method to clean form data in `views.py` before storing them in the database.

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-container">
    <!-- ASSUMING I HAVE ALREADY ADDED FIELDS DYNAMICALLY -->
    <form id = "orderForm" action="newPickupOrder/" method="post" name="processForm">
        <input type='text' name='this_field'>
        <input type='text' name='this_field'>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>   

<form id="addItemForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- BUTTON TO ADD MORE FIELDS DYNAMICALLY -->
    <button id = "addItemButton">Add item</button>
</form>

<script>
    var addItemButton = document.querySelector('#addItemButton');

    addItemButton.onclick = function(){            

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addItem/',
            data: addItemForm.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                 $("#orderForm").append(response);                     
                 console.log('Success');
            },
            error: function (response) {                    
                console.log('Error = '+response);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

**forms.py**

```
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    this_field = forms.CharField()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^newPickupOrder/$', views.pickup_order_view, name='new_pickup_order'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def add_item(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        itemForm = ItemForm()
        return HttpResponse(itemForm.as_p())

def pickup_order_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        same_name_fields = request.POST.getlist('this_field')  
        # WANT TO CLEAN DATA IN same_name_fields

        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            # ONLY PRINTS THE LAST FIELD's DATA
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/viewPickupRequests')
```

The problem I'm facing is that if I use `form.cleaned_data['this_field']`, only the last field's data is fetched i.e. in this example, the field with value `anotherTestValue` is fetched and cleaned. If I fetch the data using `request.POST.getlist('this_field')`, all the fields' data is fetched and stored as a list, but, I don't know how to clean it using `cleaned_data` method. Is there a way to apply the `cleaned_data` method to the list of field data?

Comment: How are you declaring this field in your form?

Comment: @PauloScardine I've made an edit to the question, please check it now

Comment: I think you should inherit from MultipleChoiceField and disable the validation against a choices list in order to pull this off. Unfortunately I lack the time to write a proper answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is formsets. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

```
from django.forms import formset_factory

ItemFormSet = formset_factory(ItemForm, extra=2)
```

You can the essentialy use ItemFormSet in the way you would use a normal form except that this objects is *iterable*.

You will also have to change your jquery if you want to dynamically add items. There are many examples online on how to do this. In short what you do is

1. clone one of the forms in the formset
2. clear all the values from the copied form
3. update the input's (prefixes of) id's

> Using Formsets doesn't solve the problem of fetching and validating
>   fields with same name. The issue still remains

It does however generate the end result you wanted (see below). My question would be why you need to have inputs with the same name? If there is some jquery stuff that uses these names I dont see any reason why you wouldn't be able to use name like... or assign a class to the inputs instead.

```
def pickup_order_view(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        ItemFormSet = formset_factory(ItemForm, extra=5)
        item_formset = ItemFormSet()

        template = "some_template.html"
        template_context = {'item_formset': item_formset}
        return render(request, template, template_context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ItemFormSet = formset_factory(ItemForm)
        item_formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST)

        same_name_fields=[]
        if item_formset.is_valid():

            for item_form in item_formset:
                same_name_fields.append(item_form.cleaned_data['this_field'])

            print(same_name_fields)
```

Template

```
<form id = "orderForm" action="newPickupOrder/" method="post" name="processForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ item_formset.management_form }}
    {{ for item_form in item_formset }}
        {{ item_form.as_p }}
    {{ endfor }}

    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Go to newPickupOrder/ , fill in the 5 fields, hit submit, and watch it print your list.

Comment: Using Formsets doesn't solve the problem of fetching and validating fields with same name. The issue still remains

Comment: It does however generate the end result you want. My question would be why you insist on having the same name value on the inputs in your html?

Comment: I do not insist on having fields with same name. If i may explain the situation with an example, if user 1 wanted to add 15-20 more fields, and keeping this is mind i set the extra to 15, it would be counter intuitive for user 2 who just wants 2-3 fields since the form would appear to be very long when rendered. So if I render the formset again using JQuery and AJAX to add more fields, the initial problem of similar field names would arise again. As @PauloScardine said, the issue would be solved if I do the dynamic rendering of fields entirely at the front end without creating formsets.

Comment: Thats why you set extra to say, just 1, and then use jquery to allow the user to add and delete forms as needed. Good example of this can be found here: http://stellarchariot.com/blog/2011/02/dynamically-add-form-to-formset-using-javascript-and-django/

Comment: Great link share mate! This is better than my approach of packing all field data into a hidden field. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, I can't test if this works so this is not really an answer - but the comment system is not suitable for larger code chunks so I'm posting here.

Django forms lack a field type that renders to multiple text inputs with the same name. The proper thing to do would be to write a new form field class and a new widget. Since you are not rendering the form in the template (you are using it only for validation) I will omit the widget part.

```
class AcceptAnythingMultipleChoiceField(forms.MultipleChoiceField):
    def validate(self, value):
        if self.required and not value:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['required'], 
                code='required'
            )
```

Then use this field class instead of `forms.CharField()` (you may need to pass an empty choices parameter).

[update]

> So essentially what you're saying is that I need to create new form field class and then render it to the template each time the user wants to add a new field? What if user has to add 15 fields, I'll need to create 15 classes then! I think this method won't be suitable in scenarios where number of fields required to be generated is large. I feel there should be some elegant way to do this which i'm not aware of – The OP

No, it is not what I'm saying. You probably want to subclass something like `MultipleHiddenInput` and set `AcceptAnythingMultipleChoiceField.widget` to it. You will have to create a new template based on the template for `MultipleHiddenInput` and replace input `type="hidden"` for `type="text"` (the original template is `django/forms/widgets/multiple_hidden.html`).

```
class AcceptAnythingWidget(MultipleHiddenInput):
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/multiple_visible.html'

class AcceptAnythingMultipleChoiceField(forms.MultipleChoiceField):
    widget = AcceptAnythingWidget
    def validate(self, value):
        if self.required and not value:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['required'], 
                code='required'
            )
```

This should render as many `<input name='this_field'>` as needed for instantiated forms at the frontend if you use:

```
{{ form.this_field }}
```

in the template, but will not add/remove them dynamically.

In order to do that you must plug in the JavaScript required to add/remove inputs dynamically in the widget but I will left this as an exercise for you. Look at [Form Assets (the Media class)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/media/#form-assets-the-media-class) in the docs in order to figure out how to do that.

Comment: So essentially what you're saying is that I need to create new form field class and then render it to the template each time the user wants to add a new field? What if user has to add 15 fields, I'll need to create 15 classes then! I think this method won't be suitable in scenarios where number of fields required to be generated is large. I feel there should be some elegant way to do this which i'm not aware of

Comment: No, it is not what I'm saying. My answer addresses only the server side and it would work with the HTML you presented. If it is a single instance, you can leave it to the frontend to render as many `<input name='this_field'>` as you need (or add/remove them). If you are going to use it a lot, it makes sense to subclass something like `MultipleHiddenInput` and add the javascript to add/remove items, then set `AcceptAnythingMultipleChoiceField.widget` to the new widget.

Comment: Oh yes! Now you put it like that, it makes more sense to render those forms in front-end rather than using form field class. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify this, but it is still untested.

Comment: A modification to your method is that all the fields' data could be packed into one hidden field (with some separator appended to the end of each field's data) so that in the ``views.py`` the data could be separated (based on the separator) and stored individually after splitting. Using this modification, there would be no need to create multiple hidden fields, where the initial problem of getting data from hidden-fields with similar names could arise again.

Comment: Yes, you may be interested into https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2753/

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soo as you restructure your answer by including the explanation for dynamic form field addition using JS or JQuery. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware how much the "I'll accept your answer as soon as you [do something for me]" sounds wrong?

Comment: Please don't take my comment in the wrong way, I've understood the solution and have already implemented it. I want you to get the credit and want others to benefit from your answer. Since your answer has only hinted upon the dynamic addition of fields using JS or JQuery and not actually explaining it, also, since you've said "this is not actually an answer" I want you to edit it and add the JQuery bit so that it becomes more helpful.